# golang cgi + apache login session management

Tags: go, authentication, session, cgi, session-variables

I am new to golang. I want to use golang as cgi for my apache server. I dont want  to run my golang program as a listener/server. I write .go files for each action such as login.go, logout.go, welcome.go and compile them into individual exes. I rename the exes into cgi and put them in the cgi-bin folder of apache and post from my html file to cgi bin folder. I want my go lang to serve through apache.

This is my simple html form

```
<html>
<head><title>Go Test</title></head>
<body>
<form action='cgi-bin/login.cgi' method='post'>
username : <input name='username' value='vimal'><br>
password : <input name='password' value='hello'><br>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my golang source for login. I compile into login.exe rename it to login.cgi and put it in cgibin folder of apache.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http/cgi"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

var (
    // key must be 16, 24 or 32 bytes long (AES-128, AES-192 or AES-256)
    // key = []byte("super-secret-key")
    key = uuid.NewV4().String()
    store = sessions.NewCookieStore(key)
)

func errorResponse(code int, msg string) {
    fmt.Printf("Status:%d %s\r\n", code, msg)
    fmt.Printf("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n")
    fmt.Printf("\r\n")
    fmt.Printf("%s\r\n", msg)
}

func main() {

    var req *http.Request
    var w *http.ResponseWriter
    var err error
    req, err = cgi.Request()
    if err != nil {
        errorResponse(500, "cannot get cgi request" + err.Error())
        return
    }

    if err := req.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        errorResponse(500, "cannot get cgi request" + err.Error())
    }

    username := req.FormValue("username")
    password := req.FormValue("password")
    //create session
    //store session variables like user id, user name etc., that can be accessed through other .cgi files like welcome.cgi 

    // Use req to handle request

    fmt.Printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
    fmt.Printf("<!DOCTYPE html>\n")
    fmt.Printf("<p>username: %s\n",username)
    fmt.Printf("<p>password: %s\n",password)
    fmt.Printf("req=%v\r\n", req)
}
```

I need help to create a session and store session variables like user id, username etc.,
If my another golang cgi file welcome.cgi is called it should be able to access the session variables like user id, name and print them

Please provide me with complete code. I am new to golang.
I dont want to use my golang as server. I just want to make small cgi pages.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal handlers like the ones used in several examples on the internet, that way you don't need to use a series of `fmt.Printf` to send data to the CGI server. One way that I found easy to work is by using the `cgi.Serve` function which can be used in conjunction with an `http.HandlerFunc`. Using `http.HandlerFunc` or `http.Handler` will allow you to use any session manager implementation in go that uses `http.ResponseWriter` and `http.Request`. Note however that you should not initialize your store with a randomly generated key from inside your program, and also, if you use a database back-end you will not be able to use connection polling directly from go, since your program main function will be executed on each request and it should open an close connections on each invocation.

Following is a simple example that uses the approach discussed above:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cgi"
    "os"

    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

func main() {
    // Use Serve function with an anonymous function, you can also  use instances
    // of http.Handler. The function does not need to be an anonymous function, it
    // just has to match the HandlerFunc signature
    err := cgi.Serve(http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Get the session auth key from a trusted source,
        // in this example an env var is used. You can use any mechanism you want
        // so long that you don't generate it from within this program
        key, _ := hex.DecodeString(os.Getenv("SESSION_AUTH_KEY"))
        store := sessions.NewCookieStore(key)
        // Get a session from the store if any
        sess, err := store.Get(r, "mysess")
        if err != nil {
            io.WriteString(rw, fmt.Sprintf("error reading cookies: %v", err))
            return
        }
        if sess.IsNew {
            sess.Values["val"] = 1
            //Save your store before writing anything to the client
            if err := sess.Save(r, rw); err != nil {
                io.WriteString(rw, "error writing sesion")
            } else {
                io.WriteString(rw, "new session")
            }
            return
        }
        //Write session values to validate that your session is working
        io.WriteString(rw, "Values:")
        for name, value := range sess.Values {
            io.WriteString(rw, fmt.Sprintf("name: %s, val: %v", name, value))
        }
    }))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error :%v", err)
    }
}
```